# Why my project size is so big and my .aab file size is increased highly?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle

My app's current version on the play store is 1.7... The previous **1.5 version and and current 1.7 version** are almost similar but the .aab file size difference is almost more than 2 times. The previous 1.5 version was only **10 MB** but now the 1.7 version is **24MB**. I don't add **no other extra library** from before; just added a small amount of code but the is increased highly.

The most **horrible fact** happened to me: when I go back to the 1.5 version by deleting all codes which I added after the 1.5 version... But I was surprised when I generated .aab file; the size was 23MB which was exactly 10 MB in the previous time... **I know that for someone it could not make any sense but it happened to me.**

My previous android studio version was android studio bumblebee; Now I am using Dolphin(Android Studio);

On the other hand, my project size was not so big when I was working on an update on the previous 1.5 version. It was almost 200 to 300 MB but now when I load the latest 1.7 version from GitHub; I have checked the folder properties: it was showing **32MB**… but when I build the project and run it … Its size jumped to **867MB**. If I cleaned the project; the size is reduced for a few moments but it increased highly again.
Release rules are not changed; no Proguard rules are applied: in the current and previous versions.

I have already tried these ways but failed to solve the problem :

1. Going to the previous version using GitHub version control and checked the size
2. Going to the previous version by deleting all the code manually which was added after the previous version
3. Cleaning the project
4. Generating apk file; but another problem is created here; the apk file size is two times of the .aab file size(51MB) which was exact 9.25MB in the previous time.
5. Uninstalled the new version of android studio and install the previous version of the android studio but not solved
6. My whole project **resources, Assets file size 2.5MB**

Can it happen?
I don’t write the code but the code is automatically generated because of android studio bug.

Important Properties ::
[image: Analyses of 1.5 version]
[image: Analyses of 1.7 version]

**Another Properties**
Images links are given below:

[Properties of version 1.5 ::](https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CcrQaX5CS4aDBYO3MmQp?filename=name.jpg)

[Properties of version 1.7 ::](https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/KSakXwYRjqwqc7Q0TSvg?filename=name.jpg)

Comment: I have tried hard; but don't get any solutions.